# Is it safe to use fclose() on a temporary file created by tmpfile()?

Tags: c, temporary-files

According to [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpfile), the temporary file created by `tmpfile()` is closed and deleted when the program exits normally. So far, I have not found any details regarding the use of `fclose()` on such file.

Comment: The C standard says something like "The value of a pointer to a FILE object is indeterminate after the associated file is closed".  So it looks like if you close the `tmpfile` and then the library closes it again, you'll have undefined behavior. In general, the pattern where a method allocates a resource and relies on the caller to free it should be avoided. It's in invitation to resource leakage. The C library is doing that here.

Comment: @Gene: The close of the file does not happen explicitly by the C standard library, but is a mere side effect of the program terminating. `tmpfile` opens a file with a unique name, sets the `O_CLOEXEC` flag, then *`unlink`-s* the filesystem entry of the file. Thus the only remaining link is the opened file descriptor. Once that file descriptor is closed (explicitly with `close(2)`, or implicitly at program termination, or by `execve(2)`), the file is removed from the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to use `fclose()` on a temporary file created by `tmpfile()`?

Yes, OK to close.

> The `tmpfile` function creates a temporary binary file that is different from any other existing file and that will automatically be removed when it is closed or at program termination. If the program terminates abnormally, whether an open temporary file is removed is implementation-defined.
> C17dr § 7.21.4.3 2

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Thanks @ShadowRanger

It is always safer to close it.
I had used `tmpfile()` multiple times and had always did `fclose()`.
You need to `fclose()` whether you use `tmpfile()` or `tmpfile64()`.

Comment: Nitpick: Every time you say `close()` it should be `fclose()`; the former works with `int` file descriptors, the latter with `FILE*` handles of the form returned by `tmpfile`.

Comment: Oops..my bad... I meant `fclose()`. Bdw, nice catch...